# Loopback sends wrong datatype

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, loopbackjs

In my mongodb i have several arrays, but when i load those arrays from the database they strangley are objects instead of arrays.

This strange behaviour is since a couple of days, before everything worked fine and i got arrays out of the database.

Has loopback some strange flags which are set automatically, that transform my arrays to objects or something like that?

Currently I have the newest versions in all my packages and have already tried to use older versions, but nothing changes this behaviour.

At first there was also a problem with the saving of the arrays, sometimes they were saved as objects, but since I removed all null objects from the database, only arrays were saved.

The problem occurs with the sections array

my model json is:

```
{
  "name": "Track",
  "plural": "Tracks",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "alreadySynced": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "approved": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "deletedByClient": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "sections": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": ""
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "Neuer Track"
    },
    "reason": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": ""
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "duration": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    },
    "correctnessscore": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    },
    "evaluation": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I have also already tried to change the type object to array but without success

Comment: can you please post your model.json / js

Comment: @AnouarKacem i've updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not seeing any array type in your model and I am not sure what is exactly your problem.

> Has loopback some strange flags which are set automatically, that
>   transform my arrays to objects or something like that?

No loopback has no flags and doesn't transform any data type unless you set it !
So if you define a property as object and you are passing an array without validating the data type this will change the type of your data and save it as object instead of array.

Lets define an array in your Track model :

```
"property": {
   "type": "array"
}
```

Do you need array of objects?

```
"property": {
       "type": ["object"]
    }
```

Strings ?

```
 "property": {
           "type": ["string"]
        }
```

Numbers ?

```
 "property": {
           "type": ["number"]
        }
```

Read more about loopback types [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html).

Comment: I found out that the strange transformation of datatype didn't occur because of loopback, there was another bug in the application
and I need an array of objects, so "type":["object"] is the right one for me 
thank you for the comprehensive reply